# Excel Solver - Limit Number of Variables

Tags: excel, solver

Here is the problem
Excel solver need to change the values of variables a, b, c, d, e, f in a way that it gives the optimization solution considering a constraint that Count of Non Zero values for variables a, b, c, d, e, f should be less than 3

Read through many online articles but didn't find a solution

Comment: Please provide some input about the constraint, or is the only constraint that the count of non-zero values should be less than 3? If that's the case there are too many optimal solutions...

Comment: Each variable has different weightage,  A variable has a weightage 0.1 similarly others variables has weightage i.e  B (0.2), C (0.3), D(0.4),E(0.5),F(0.6). Values for variables need to change in a way that sumproduct value * weightage should be equal to 12 but only 3 variables need to be non zero.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you should have the Solver Add-In (see: [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/load-the-solver-add-in-in-excel-612926fc-d53b-46b4-872c-e24772f078ca) is you do not have it)

Next I created a sheet like this (using control+backquoot to show the formulas)

[image]

After make field G3 active, and click on `Data/Solver` via the menu.

In Dutch 'Solver' is 'Oplosser', the rest of the text in this screenshot is also in Dutch (you can say thanks to Microsoft for that! (i do not know where you can do that!))

[image]

Anyway, after entering the correct values, and hitting the 'Solve' (or 'Opslossen') button, I do get:

[image]

A correct solution to your problem is: A=4; E=4; F=16 and (B=0; C=0; D=0)

I did assume the numbers in A...F should not have decimals, be: `'geheeltallig'`